# graph of dependent variable after years of restructuring in panel data

Tags: regression, time-series, international-economics, paneldata, stata

i'm not very able to use **stata**. For my thesis, I have a panel data(1970-2017) for different countries and a lot of variables.
In this dataset, there is a dummy (dhairendH) that is equal to one in the years where a country end a debt restructuration.
i would like to graph 3 different dependent variable (it is better if they are overlapped) depending on the 7 years after the restructuration, like the image attached.

The name of the the dependent variables are gini_disp, gini_cons and ginipretax. Obviously, I have variables years and CountryName. The name of the dummy is dhairendH.
[image]

Comment: In order to get answer for questions like this you need to provide at least minimal working example, otherwise it is very unlikely that even someone willing can help you. Furthermore, in addition to MWE what have you tried already? Please show us your attempt as well

Comment: The general syntax for plotting variables y1 y2 and y3 against x in Stata is `twoway scatter y1 y2 y3 x`. You can also substitute `line` or `connected` for `scatter`. See the [manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-2graphtwoway.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Guys, I have listed all the variables and the problem.. I don't know if is it possible to upload all the dataset, but tell me what you need :) I  did a lot of graphs with twoway, for example: twoway (scatter gini_cons year), but the graph that I would to do it's more difficult. Because I would tell to stata to consider only the years when the dummy==1, and on the x axis i wish there was years after restructuring, not the years of the dataset, i.e. (0-1-2-...7) like in the example